# Use .htaccess to redirect virtual subdomains except for www

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm already using http.d to drive (via 301 redirect) all non-www traffic to the www version of the site.  I.e. example.com redirects to www.example.com.

This works perfectly.

I would now like to allow users to set up virtual subdomains.  So, if somebody visits bob.example.com, I'd like mod_rewrite to actually serve the page www.example.com/page.php?user=bob.

Since all of my Google history is set up to index the www version of the site, I don't want to lose that, so I want www excluded.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Honestly, I don't want to give them a full site under the subdomain - basically, just one page.  So file.php should not exist.  Just show page.php?user=bob if the bob.example.com is set.

Comment: No, redirecting would change the url in the browser.  A proper mod_rewrite should let the user see their url in the browser, while silently serving the proper url.

The classic example is:

    `RewriteEngine on`
    `RewriteRule ^red.html$ blue.html`

The user types in red.html, but sees the content of blue.html - and is none the wiser.

Comment: But rewrite is possible ONLY if you don't change domain name in URL by using `http://...` in target URI. Are `DocumentRoot` value for `bob.example.com` and `www.example.com` pointing to same directory?

Comment: Yes.  I have the virtual wildcard domain set up to direct it all to the same directory on the server.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?!www\.)([^.]+)\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ page.php?user=%1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Yes, but I want it to be dynamic.  bob.example.com, john.example.com, fred.example.com - all redirect to page.php?user=bob, ?user=john, ?user=fred, respectively.  

However, I don't want to break www.example.com.

Comment: Ah, great.  Also, if a user has input no subdomain at all - i.e. example.com - it should function as normal (which is a 301 redirect to www.example.com), right?

Comment: Yes that's right, this rule won't match `www.example.com` or `example.com` so that `www` adding rule will work as before.

Comment: Does not appear to work.  Crud.  Maybe I need to double check the apache http.d settings?

Comment: That has worked on my Apache. To test add `R` flag in `RewriteRule` as: `RewriteRule ^ page.php?user=%1 [L,QSA,R]`